# Setting Standard Deviation to ggplot2 boxplot with 2 factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, factors

after searching for a while, I've decided to ask my first question :

it's pretty simple actually - I am plotting with ggplot2 and unfortunately the whiskers (in purple) are overlapping each other (they're not in the position they should be)

It is caused due to using different arguments from different websites (I did not find any guide for plotting with 2 different factors in ggplot2 AND ADDING SD TO THE PLOT)

so in practice I took the sd example from a different guide which consists of no factors at all.

here's my code :

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=Usage, y=`Panas result`, fill=Positive)) +
geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(), width=0.5) +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10, 45)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#33FFFF","seagreen2"),labels=c('נייטרלי', "חיובי")) +
labs(fill = "מניפולציה",title="תוצאות שאלון הפנס כתלות בסיווג זמן המסך וסוג המניפולציה", x="זמן         מסך", y =   
"תוצאות שאלון הפנס") +
stat_summary(
fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x),
fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x),
geom = "errorbar",
color = "purple",
width = .5,
orientation = 'Usage') +
theme_classic()
```

that yeilds the following plot :

[image]

again - All I ask is for the purple whiskers to be in their positions (and not one on top of the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `stat_summary` defaults to `position="identity"`. To align your errorbars with the box plots and dodge them by  the same amount you have to use the same `position` in `stat_summary` as for the box plots, i.e. in your case `position = position_dodge()` will do as you have set `width = .5` for both.

Using some a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.5) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10, 45)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#33FFFF", "seagreen2"), labels = c("נייטרלי", "חיובי")) +
  labs(
    fill = "מניפולציה", title = "תוצאות שאלון הפנס כתלות בסיווג זמן המסך וסוג המניפולציה", x = "זמן         מסך", y =
      "תוצאות שאלון הפנס"
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x),
    fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x),
    geom = "errorbar",
    color = "purple",
    width = .5,
    position = position_dodge()
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually works :)
Simple as that...